# How to check the validity of the credentials from Amazon Cognito at server side(java)

Tags: amazon-cognito

Now I am developing some iOS app. This app uses Amazon Cognito to make each user's authenticated id and credentials.

On the other hand, this app uses my original WebAPI server. I want to check the user's validity on the server by using Cognito id and/or credentials.

Which AWS API should I use for this validation at the server(java code)?

Answer (score 1):

The information in the only other answer seems to be a bit incorrect so I wanted to update this a little bit.

The API Gateway method that is mentioned is great and works, but it is still doing the same thing that you can do manually.  With API Gateway it does the signing checks, but it is still using the token that is passed, validating the claims as discussed below, then just normalizing it into the context object for you to use.

You can send any token and it can be validated that the given token was signed by AWS.  ***This value can not be spoofed.***  **If the validation is successful then you can rely on all the data in claims being the same values which existed when the token was signed by Amazon.**

A comment in the other answer correctly indicates the link with this information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

With Javascript, one can validate the token with the following:

https://gist.github.com/bradennapier/c996672944ebf511410eb45c0395f525

Note that this is a first pass during a feature discovery that was done and does not represent a production-ready solution.  Please use as a reference only.

AWS also has some examples available for both javascript and python: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt - I did notice when looking through that example that it would not validate properly when given an `access` token and would only work for `id` tokens.

Comment: I like this answer. Just a quick clarification on the question and "the other answer" :): The question was specifically about sending the Cognito "IdentityId", not a JWT. The IdentityId is not signed and not verifiable it is essentially what should be in the "sub" claim in a JWT.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the Amazon Cognito-issued IdentityId from the device to the backend is not a secure since the IdentityId could be spoofed. The best way to securely validate that API requests are made by an authenticated user is by using [Amazon API Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/). You can use Amazon AWS API Gateway to proxy your existing backend (or use API Gateway+Lambda to replace the backend) and API Gateway can optionally and automatically authenticate the requests using the [AWS Signature Version 4 Signing Process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have not known the Amazon API Gateway till now. I try to check it.

Comment: ehh??? so, sending the token to APIG can't be spoofed? 
You can send the token anywhere.
In fact, there is a documentation for from aws to verify the tokens on the backend 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html
There is also a way to do all the auth logic in the backend
using this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

Comment: API Gateway can automatically authorize requests signed using AWS v4 Signing (the same method use to authorize other AWS request). Using AWS Mobile SDK those requests also include the user's identity as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945385/how-to-pass-cognito-user-information-to-lambda/32954079#32954079. At least that's the way it used to be and I presume still is. You can see this question and answer existed from some time ago so it doesn't take into account things like Cognito's User Pools, but I presume they still work similarly.