# How to pass cognito user information to lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda

I'm developing application based on API Gateway and Lambda. I configured POST /subscribe as "AWS_IAM". So now it cannot accessible directly, but I can access to API with Cognito authentication.

Now problem is my Lambda doesn't know who is the API caller. How to know that?

I have 2 users: "Bob" and "John". My Lambda need to know that caller is Bob or John.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the Cognito Identity ID from the `identity` property of the `context` parameter (`context.identity`) as explained in the [context Object Properties section of the Lambda Programming Model help topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html#programming-model-context-object-properties). Once you have the Cognito unique identifier, you can use Cognito Sync's APIs with your developer credentials to look up information stored about this user in Cognito or you can use that identifier to map the ID to user information stored in elsewhere.

Make sure that API Gateway is configured for AWS_IAM (as you mentioned) and make sure that "Invoke with caller credentials" is checked under the method's "Integration Request" settings.

Comment: Thanks. It works on GET method. But mapping not working on DELETE, POST and other methods. is there any special configuration?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. I'll ping the API Gateway team and ask them for a hand here.

Comment: I changed context type to "text/plain" from "application/json".

Comment: FYI: The Amazon API Gateway team has resolved this issue. So if you regenerate your JS SDK you should no longer have the problem.

Comment: The option "Invoke with caller credentials" is grayed out and I cannot turn in on. Do you know why?

Comment: @Kamchatka make sure that you have "Authorization" setting in API Gateway's Method Request set to something other than "None".

Comment: Looks like it only works if it's IAM, but not if the Authorization is Cognito.

Comment: So to invoke the API with Authorization set to Cognito, we set the Authorization header to the IdToken, as obtained from cognito.initiate_auth, etc.  But in this case, the Cognito Identity ID is missing inside the lambda.  To get the Cognito Identity ID inside the lambda, we need to auth with IAM_AUTH and "invoke with caller credentials".  (Is this all right so far?) If so... how is the request to the API authed?  Using IdToken in the Authorization header gives: "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter., Signature parameter, etc" errors.  It needs to be signed some other way?

Comment: @billc I'm not sure what you're trying to to exactly, but AFAIK API Gateway doesn't ever interpret an Open ID "ID Token" as an authorization value (it shouldn't). See [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html) for different ways to authorize API Gateway APIs. If you're using Cognito and an [API-Gateway-generated SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html), the SDK can authorize calls for you if you give it an AWS Access Key and Secret Key.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kamchatka said, looks like the masked response only works in case API Gateway Authorization is configured for AWS_IAM but not with Cognito. In Cognito case, we don't need "Invoke with caller credentials" because caller information lies claims inside the event object already. E.g: event.requestContext.authorizer.claims. For example, this is my claims object.

```
{
  sub: '80f12e45-e1ba-47d8-8a53-352fe6a3d798',
  email_verified: 'true',
  iss: cognito-arn,
  'cognito:username': '111112',
  origin_jti: '29b8f18a-ee6b-4b16-9691-36efbd3b19f9',
  aud: '10k1opd4kei0gc3fe5f3cb8q2h',
  event_id: '39595d16-abcf-4f5d-8f19-e1487c088b0d',
  token_use: 'id',
  auth_time: '1658731342',
  exp: 'Mon Jul 25 07:42:22 UTC 2022',
  iat: 'Mon Jul 25 06:42:22 UTC 2022',
  jti: '6b713944-9423-4437-87dd-02e5ac9e673a',
  email: caller-email
}
```