# Cognito Identity Id in AWS IOT event handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I have an AWS Lambda function called on ["subscribe" IOT event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html). Client subscribes to IOT with Cognito credentials. Is it possible to get Cognito Identity Id in the Lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the Cognito Identity ID from the `identity` property (in case of noe.js runtime)  of the context parameter (`context.identity`) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945385/how-to-pass-cognito-user-information-to-lambda/32954079#32954079).

Also, I don't really understand the use-case of Cognito Identity ID. I think you should be able to uniquely identify your devices using `clientId` property of the MQTT message.

Comment: I have a web application that subscribes to IOT. In backend I should know the user who creates a subscription. If clientId will contain the user id, then it will be unsafe because web application can change the clientId.

Comment: It does not work for me. There is no identity property in context object.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I use node.js 6.10